# Product is a perfect $k$th power iff each of $a,b,c$ is a perfect $k$th power.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math

Given that $k \geq 2$ is an integer. If $a,b,c \in N$ and they are pairwise coprime, then prove that $abc$ is a $k$th power if and only if each of $a,b,c$ is a $k$th power.

My try:

Let $$abc=p^k$$ for some $p \in N$

On the contrary let us assume that $a$ is not a $k$th power.
So $a$ will be of the form:
$$a=p^k-m$$
Then we have:
$$m=a(bc-1)$$
I am stuck here.

Comment: You should use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic

Comment: mathSE reviewers will want you to focus on the hint of Alex J Best, (which does in fact solve the problem) and edit your query to indicate how you think the hint *might* be used to solve your query.   Focus (also) on **why** the premise that $(a,b,c)$ are pairwise coprime is relevant.  Please do **not** respond with a comment.  Instead, edit your query.  Actually, I would normally have given a *hint-answer*.  However, because of the comment of Alex J Best, such a response from me would be nothing more than a duplication of his insight.